# Firefox-Addon SDK jQuery.get() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon-sdk, http-get

I am developing a simple firefox tool with firefox-addon SDK that show some stored data.

This is the code for the list panel:

```
var list = panels.Panel({
  width: 600,
  height: 500,
  contentURL: data.url('list/list.html'),
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.10.1.js'),
                      data.url('list/list.js')],
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  onShow: function() {
    this.postMessage('focus'); 
  },
  onMessage: function(message) {
    require('sdk/tabs').open(message);
  }
});
```

This is the code of list.js:

```
$.get("http://localHost:0000/clips", function(data) {
    console.log( "done");
    //do something with data
}
```

but it doesn't work. The message "done" isn't showed.

I also try with jQuery.getJSON() method but it doesn't work.

I am sure that the server side sends the correct data because at the url I can see it.

Why is the list.js class unable to execute the $.get() method?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you're missing a `)` at the end of your `$.get` call.

Comment: Unfortunately I have forgot `)` only here and not also in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts follow the same origin policy. Read the data from main.js.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand exactly what you mean. I want that the main calls list.js which is responsible to do the GET request.

Comment: The GET request is dropped for security reasons, check the error console.

Comment: try using JSONP  See  Also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786681. Cross-domain ajax was not supported previous versions of add-on-sdk